# How to tell autootools configure NOT to check for a function

Tags: ruby, autotools, configure, automake, autoconf

I am working with the Ruby source which has a `configure.in` script with the following line `AC_CHECK_FUNCS(clock_gettime)`

On my system it WILL find such a function and Ruby will go ahead and build a binary that depends on this function. However, this function is non-portable to other operating systems so i would like to tell the `./configure` script NOT to use this function even if it does find it.

It would be perfect if i can instruct `./configure` not to use this function by a command line option, i heavily prefer not to modify the `configure.in` script if possible. My question is, how do I do this? I can't seem to find the correct command line option to use.

Comment: You may be able to do this by clever choice of environment setting, but there will be a command-line option for it only if the configure script goes out of its way to provide one.  The output of `./configure --help` would list any such option.

Comment: But I don't understand why you're asking.  Who cares whether the function is available on other systems?  Except when you're cross-compiling, the point of the `configure` script is to configure *for the machine on which you're building*.  The binary you then build might also be usable on other, sufficiently similar systems, but you cannot under any circumstances expect it to work on a completely different operating system.  Instead, you configure and build separately for a different OS.

Comment: @JohnBollinger because Ruby is just one part of a larger app that needs to be distributed as a binary for the end-user. So i'm trying to build a  Ruby binary that runs on as many systems as possible

Comment: The widest portability you can even hope for is to different versions of substantially the same operating system, e.g. GNU / Linux.  In that case, configure and build against the oldest version of the relevant C library  (i.e. glibc) that you want to accommodate, and test on as many versions as possible.  The point to understand here is that your list of potential problems is far broader than any one function, or even anything that `configure` might test for.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, how do I do this? I can't seem to find the correct command line option to use.

First, there is good advice in the comments: for best results, build on the oldest system you can find (or set up) and try to reduce the dependencies as much as possible.  glibc is good about symbol versioning and compatibility, but many other libraries are not.

That said, if you really want to circumvent a check, the way to do it is to pre-populate a cache file with the results you want.  One simple way to make the cache is to run configure, then edit it, then re-run configure.

The cache variable naming scheme [is documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.68/html_node/Cache-Variable-Names.html), but normally you can find what you want by just searching for the function name in `config.cache`.

Maybe it's even possible to set the cache variable on the `configure` command line -- but I have never tried this.